# rm file "Operation not permitted" even when sudo

Tags: macos, python, rm

Im working with python 2.7 and I was having import errors with random, So I checked the path and noticed it was using random.pyc instead of random.py

I tried to remove the file but it won't work.

```
sudo rm -rf /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/random.pyc
```

and rm -R gives me this error even when I say y

```
sudo rm -R /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/random.pyc
override rw-r--r--  root/wheel restricted,compressed for /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/random.pyc? y
rm: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/random.pyc: Operation not permitted
```

What should I do?

Edit: My whole "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/" is full of .pyc and .pyo files and import doesn't work on any of them (unless I use idle)

Comment: What version of macOS? It's probably SIP if you're on El Capitan or later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: This is normal. `.pyc` files are precompiled Python files. They contain the same data as the `.py` files adjacent to them. If you are having problems with the `random` module, you are probably doing something else wrong, and you should probably ask a question about your code on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

More generally: You cannot, and should not, modify files under the `/System` directory. They are part of the operating system -- modifying them will cause your computer to work incorrectly.

macOS prevents system files from being modified (other than by system updates) using a mechanism called System Integrity Protection, or SIP. [It is possible to disable SIP](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016462-CH5-SW1), but this should generally not be necessary, even for developers.